# Как использовать событие afterSave в Yii2?

Tags: yii2, события, model

Как использовать событие afterSave?

Пишу в модели, но оно не вызывается при сохранении данных в БД.

```
public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes)
{
var_dump("ooooooooo");
}
```

Вот моя модель:

```
<?php
namespace app\modules\userpanel\models\userpanel;
use app\models\db_table\Tablename;

use yii\base\Model;
use Yii;

use yii\base\Event;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class form extends Model
{
    public $user_id;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [

            ['user_id', 'required'],



        ];
    }







public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes)
    {
        parent::afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes);
        var_dump("ooooooooo");
    }



public function addZakazDB()
    { 

       $model2 = new Tablename();
       $model2->user_id = $this->user_id;
       return $model2->save();
    }



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы упустили родительский метод:

```
public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes){
    parent::afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes);
    //ниже ваш код
    var_dump("ooooooooo");
}
```

Почему? Потому, что мы передаем в родительский метод все те же параметры и запускаем его, а потом делаем все нам необходимое.

Comment: Добавил но не работает. Точно так-же добавил в модель.

Comment: или `parent::afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes);` вызывать нужно из метода в котором вы добавляем данные в БД?

Comment: что значит "родительский метод все те же параметры "?

Comment: этот код должен работать,
значит у Вас не работает save

Comment: Как уже ответил gudfar - у вас скорее всего до save дело не доходит. Насчет параметров. Имеется ввиду $insert, $changedAttributes

Comment: @UrmuzTagizade  Я вставил в свой вопрос код моей модели. Покажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так, почему событие не срабатывает?

Comment: Где вы вызываете addZakazDB() ? У вас такая каша в коде.

Comment: @Urmuz Tagizade Почему каша? А где нужно вызвать? Например в контроллере вызываю. Что вы имеете  в виду?